# Want to keep relationship between two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables, PRODUCT and DISCOUNT, that have a many to many relationship.  The table that maintains this relationship is PRODUCTHASDISCOUNT.  I want to delete records from PRODUCTHASDISCOUNT if a PRODUCT IS deleted, but not if a DISCOUNT is deleted for some reason.  In that case the product should be assigned a different discount before the DISCOUNT id is ever deleted.  So I tried a ON DELETE RESTRICT on the foreign key but that isn't working.  I'm using an InnoDB so I cannot use SET DEFAULT.  Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
prodName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
price DECIMAL(6,2),
availability BOOLEAN,
description VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
size VARCHAR(20),
weight VARCHAR(10),
catID INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT '1'
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE DISCOUNT (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
percentOff DECIMAL(4,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT "0.0"
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTHASDISCOUNT (
prodID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
percentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
startDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
endDate TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (prodID, percentID),
FOREIGN KEY (prodID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (percentID) REFERENCES PERCENT(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to mention that the error I get when I try to CREATE TABLE PRODUCTHASDISCOUNT is ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'my_slabicht2.PRODUCTHASDISCOUNT' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISCOUNT(id)` instead of `PERCENT(id)`

```
`CREATE TABLE PRODUCTHASDISCOUNT (
prodID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
percentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
startDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
endDate TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (prodID, percentID),
FOREIGN KEY (prodID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (percentID) REFERENCES DISCOUNT(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;`
```

Comment: THank you!...I think it's too late and I need a break.  This was just a stupid mistake.  Thank you for catching it for me.